# Changing stylesheet of the widgets with PyQt5 when key pressed

Tags: python, pyqt5, qtstylesheets

How can I change the buttons stylesheet in PyQt5 when I press a key from keyboard?

Like I did with hover, and pressed for click.

```
css = """
    QPushButton {
    background: #F7F7F7;
    font-size: 22px;
    border-style: none;}
    
    QPushButton::hover {
    background: #D3D3D3;}
    
    QPushButton::pressed{
    background: #C3C3C3;
    color: purple;}
    
    """
```

Comment: You can't, and it wouldn't have a lot of sense, as it would be extremely difficult to implement and would be rarely used. QSS is based on CSS2.1 which only provides limited implementation of mouse events and widget states, while keyboard events are much more complex and have potentially thousands of combination. Please explain what you're *actually* trying to achieve and what should happen at a (and which) keypress.

Comment: I think people are allowed to want what they want and try what they want to try. In this case, I don't think [stylesheets](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/stylesheet-reference.html) offer anything to respond to keyPress events. So to get this functionality, you'll have to do it in code. Alternatively, if assigning a specific Alt+Key to your button is acceptable, you can add an ampersand (&) in text of your button in before the letter you want to assign. For example `&Print` will assign Alt+P shortcut to that button.